# How to throw a c++ exception for out of range

Tags: c++, exception

I have a simple c++ method that prints Ascii characters 0=255 on cout. Here it is :

```
void print_ascii()
{    
  unsigned char c = 0;

  while (c < 255)    
  {
    cout << c << endl;
    c = c+1;
  }

}// end print_ascii()

int main()
{
   print_ascii();
}
```

The above code worked fine but I overflowed the char when I tried it while (c <= 255) because it exceeded the unsigned char sign.

My question is how do I throw an exception for these scenarios (*offbyone*) because it is sometimes hard to remember the upperbound limit of a type?

Comment: Actually, it is impossible to "overflow" an `unsigned char`. It is defined to wrap-around. You do not need to remember the upper limit of a numeric type: use `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()` and move on.

Comment: If you want something that throws on your behalf, consider using something like the [SafeInt library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd570023.aspx).

Comment: ok i will remind you.  it is (2^(sizeof(the-type)*8))-1.

Comment: It does overflow and windows console goes in infinte loop and I literally have to restart. I am using gcc/MinGW. STL vectors know their size and they do throw if you go out of range and throw but primitive types don't throw when you increment.

Comment: It's somewhat pedantic but c didn't overflow, the largest it can get is 255 so it works for < 255 and loops forever for <=255. It isn't looping forever because of an overflow, it's looping forever because that's what the code does. 255+1=0.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow doesn't "work" on integers in general, and certainly an `unsigned char` will just wrap around.

You could do something like this:

```
while (c <= 255)
{
    cout << c << endl;
    int temp = c + 1;
    if (temp > 255) throw whatever_excpetion;
    c = t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned, unsigned chat will be 0 after overflow. you may use it in this do-while

```
unsigned char x = 0;
do{
     code;
     ++x;
} while (x!=0);
```

but I'm not sure it is easy to read. Naive one:

```
for (c = 0;true;++c){
     code;
     if (c == numeric_limits <unsigned char>:: max ()) break;
}
```

Comment: Alright thank you all guys for the help. Here is what I ended up doing and it works. </br> unsigned char j = 0;

  while (true)
  {
    cout << j << endl;
    ++j;
    if (j == numeric_limits <unsigned char>:: max ()) break;
  }

Comment: <code> unsigned char j = 0; while (true) { cout << j << endl; ++j; if (j == numeric_limits <unsigned char>:: max ()) break; } <code>